# jQuery UI Slider not changing default Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have setup a slider with jQuery UI, and the correct default value of 60 is displayed. but the slider is still on the very left. It should move to value 60.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Xfg.jpg

Tried different options found here on StackOverflow but nothing helped.

```
var gewichtSlider = $("#gewicht-slider").slider({
    min: 40,
    max: 200,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#gewicht").val(ui.value).trigger('change');
        $("#gewicht-label").text(ui.value);
        $("#gewicht-handle").text(ui.value + ' kg');
    }
});
gewichtSlider.slider('option', 'slide').call(gewichtSlider, null, {value: 60});
```

The slider is not moving.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tz6pea5c/

Comment: 60 seems very close to the minimum (40) does it move if you set it to 100?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty: Please see jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tz6pea5c/

Comment: @MickVader I created a fiddle for this. No matter what default value it is always on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of slider is set using `value` property. To show initial value in your label, you need to add a `create` callback, which is being called right after the slider was initialized. Then, you need to add a `slide` callback to react to sliding event and change label's value accordingly. Lastly, I removed a hidden input field and showed you how to retrieve a value from the slider itself using a button click. If you need a value to be saved in a hidden input field instead, then you can modify `setSliderValue` function like that:

```
function setSliderValue(value) {
  $sliderLabel.text(value + " kg");
  $("#your-hidden-field-id").val(value);
}
```

Bellow is the full working example:

```js
var defaultValue = 60;
var $sliderLabel = $(".slider-after");

function setSliderValue(value) {
  $sliderLabel.text(value + " kg");
}

var $gewichtSlider = $("#gewicht-slider").slider({
    min: 40,
    max: 200,
    value: defaultValue,
    create: function() {
      setSliderValue(defaultValue);
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
     setSliderValue(ui.value);
    }
});

$("#current-value").click(function() {
 alert($gewichtSlider.slider( "value" ) + " kg");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="gewicht-container question-container">
  <label for="gewicht">Wie schwer bist du?</label>
  <p class="question-desc">Dies ist eine wichtige Angabe für die Matraztenhärte. Daten werden nicht gespeichert ;)</p>

  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-before">
      Gewicht
    </div>
    <div id="gewicht-slider">
      <div id="gewicht-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-after">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>

  <hr/>
  <button id="current-value">Get current value</button>
</div>
```

Comment: that is great, but the handle does not contain this value. Is there a way to trigger a "slide" after the value is set?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/34eg1xc9/21/

**JavaScript**

```
var gewichtSlider = $("#gewicht-slider");
gewichtSlider.slider({
  min: 40,
  max: 200,
  create: function(e, ui) {
    $("#gewicht-handle").css({
      width: "3em",
      textAlign: "center"
    }).text('60 kg');
    gewichtSlider.slider('value', 60);
  },
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#gewicht").val(ui.value).trigger('change');
    $("#gewicht-handle").text(ui.value + ' kg');
  }
});
```

I could not find `$("#gewicht-label")` in your code. I also made use of `create` callback to setup the slider.